# Maven 2: how to deinstall artefact from local repository?

Tags: maven-2

Is there any way to 'nicely' deinstall artefact previously installed into local repository by Maven 2? I have original `pom.xml` file and of course I can manually remove artifact but I'd like to do it in some more clean way than manual delete.

Googled around but no luck, maybe I just searched in wrong direction.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at this Maven Dependency plugin goal: [purge-local-repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html):

> The purpose of the dependency:purge-local-repository goal is to purge
>   (delete and optionally re-resolve) artifacts from the local maven
>   repository.

However, I think you may loose those other 'handmade' dependencies you manually uploaded to only your local repository.

I'd say that there's nothing bad about manually removing related files (and folders) from you local repository.

Comment: Actually I'd like something like 'purge local repository from project artifact but not dependencies' but this could be starting point, +1.

Comment: There're options like 'include(s)', 'exclude(s)' and 'manualExclude(s)', which, properly used, might help you achieving your goal.